# CakePHP DebugKit / Plugins webroot not being found

Tags: php, cakephp

I've installed CakePHP's debug kit but it's not loading correctly on my pages, its just a mess of text and arrays at the bottom of the page. My browser is saying that it's getting a 404 on:

```
/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css
/debug_kit/js/jquery.js
/debug_kit/js/js_debug_toolbar.js
/debug_kit/img/cake.icon.png
```

...so it's not finding the webroots for plugins properly. I have directed my browser to these pages and other combinations i could think of (e.g: /debugkit/css... or /debug_kit/webroot...) but nothing is working.

From my google searches it seems like a problem that a few people have had but I haven't seen a solution yet.

I have removed the 'sql_dump' element from the bottom of the layout page and still nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone else having this problem:

It's not a direct solution, but sort of a little hack

copy the contents of `app/Plugin/DebugKit/webroot`

to a new folder `app/webroot/debug_kit`

The problem is that CakePHP is not seeing the Plugins webroot, but this will bypass this problem.

Comment: Although not an answer but a hack, it actually works, it's 2018 and I still have this problem.

My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927143/cakephp-debugkit-assets-not-loading-with-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have you got the right version of DebugKit for the version of CakePHP that you are using?

Secondly have you included it in your $components (usually in the App Controller) ?

```
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Cookie',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar'
        );
```

Are you loading it in bootstrap? i.e. CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');

Lastly have you got Configure::write('debug', 2); in core.php?

When working it will appear as an icon top right of the screen.

Comment: I'm in 2.3.8, the debug kit github says its for 2.2.0 and higher so thats ok.
I have included it in my $components array.
And yes I do have Configure::write('debug', 2); in core.php :(

Comment: what about loading it in bootstrap? and you are using PHP 5.3.0 or higher?

Comment: Yep I've got `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');` in bootstrap.php and I'm using PHP 5.4.0

Comment: Mmn, I've had a similar problem before where the page itself had formatting issues, which affected DebugKit from rendering properly. What happens if you display the same page with debug set at 0. Does the page itself load okay? Are all your html tags properly closed?

Comment: Everything is loading perfectly with debug at 0, and i've check my layout and the html is fine from what I can see. I have a feeling its a routing issue, but there's nothing strange in routes.php either, `CakePlugin::routes();` is there

Comment: Okay, difficult to diagnose from afar - have you looked at this possible issue? https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/issues/122

Comment: Yeah I've had a look at that, none of the solutions worked :/