# CakePHP 3.1.4 DebugKit not finding Routes

Tags: debugging, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm sure Debug Kit is enabled. I've activated it with a mysql Datasource, debug is set to true. After recognizing this:

**NetworkError: 404 Not Found - [http://localhost/debug_kit/js/toolbar.js](http://localhost/debug_kit/js/toolbar.js__)**

I tried to follow the steps from this post:

[CakePHP DebugKit / Plugins webroot not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048223/cakephp-debugkit-plugins-webroot-not-being-found)

and now have this errror:
**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/debug_kit/toolbar/8475f531-de95-4698-90b0-f8b1ebcf7960"**

Can Anyone help? Whats going on? Anyone else have had this Problem?
It's a complete fresh CakePhp-Installation (Ubuntu, Apache2), just added the debug_kit-Datasource in app.php. I can not find any misstake, could you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, it was a problem with Vhost-Configration.
Tested the same app on different server and it was working.

Seems that AllowOverride was overwritten anywhere in the webserver configuration.